# Game not rotating PortraitUpsideDown

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

The orientation is shown in 'support interface orientations' in the info.plist file, however still does not rotate when turned.

I am looking to make Portrait & Portraitupsidedown

This is from the RootViewController.m

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

        //
        // There are 2 ways to support auto-rotation:
        //  - The OpenGL / cocos2d way
        //     - Faster, but doesn't rotate the UIKit objects
        //  - The ViewController way
        //    - A bit slower, but the UiKit objects are placed in the right place
        //

    #if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
        //
        // EAGLView won't be autorotated.
        // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
        // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
        //

    #elif GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationCCDirector
        //
        // EAGLView will be rotated by cocos2d
        //
        // Sample: Autorotate only in landscape mode
        //
        if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        } else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
        }

        // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation,
        // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
        return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

    #elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
        //
        // EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
        //
        // Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
        //
        // return YES for the supported orientations

        return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation));

    #else
    #error Unknown value in GAME_AUTOROTATION

    #endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION


        // Shold not happen
        return NO;
    }

    //
    // This callback only will be called when GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    //
    #if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        //
        // Assuming that the main window has the size of the screen
        // BUG: This won't work if the EAGLView is not fullscreen
        ///
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

        if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
            rect = screenRect;


        else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            rect.size = CGSizeMake( screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width );

        CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
        float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

        if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
            rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
            rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
        }
        glView.frame = rect;
    }
    #endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController


From the AppDelegate.m file I also have;

    // Init the window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Try to use CADisplayLink director
    // if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    //
    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //
    //
    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    //
    // VERY IMPORTANT:
    // If the rotation is going to be controlled by a UIViewController
    // then the device orientation should be "Portrait".
    //
    // IMPORTANT:
    // By default, this template only supports Landscape orientations.
    // Edit the RootViewController.m file to edit the supported orientations.
    //

    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:NO];


    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [viewController setView:glView];

    // make the View Controller a child of the main window
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have other games, using Cocos2d that I have managed to get to rotate and I cross-checked the settings with those, they are the same, so I cannot figure out why it is not rotating?

EDIT -

This could be a telling message about this...

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing it? Set a breakpoint and what's going on.

Comment: I wasn't sure where to put the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding rootViewController

```
[window setRootViewController: viewController];
```

Comment: Hi @gururaj.T that works better, it now rotates, but everything goes off screen, ie it rotates and a black screen appears (so everything goes off the screen)

Comment: Good solution is to port your code to Cocos2d 2.x or 3.x

Answer (score 0):

In your rootview controller, comment out

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
    rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
    rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
}
glView.frame = rect;
```